# Is this morphism of schemes required to be induced by $k\to k[T_0,T_1,\cdots,T_n]/I$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In page 55~56 of Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, there is a paragraph as follows:

Definition 3.47. Let $k$ be a field. An affine variety over $k$ is the affine scheme associated to a finitely generated algebra over $k$. An algebraic variety over $k$ is a $k$-scheme $X$ such that there exists a covering by a finite number of affine open subschemes $X_i$ which are affine varieties over $k$.

If $\varphi_i:X_i\to \mathrm{Spec}(k[T_0,T_1,\cdots,T_n]/I)$ is isomorphic, let $\psi:X\to \mathrm{Spec}k$ be the morphism together with $k$-scheme $X$, is  $\psi\circ\varphi_i^{-1}$ required to be induced by the canonical morphism $k\to k[T_0,T_1,\cdots,T_n]/I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  When we say an open subscheme $X_i$ is an affine variety, we mean it is isomorphic to an affine variety *as a $k$-scheme*, so that the isomorphism $\varphi_i$ forms a commutative diagram with the maps to $\operatorname{Spec} k$.  This means exactly that $\psi\circ\varphi_i^{-1}$ is required to be induced by the canonical morphism.

Comment: But I have another comprehension:

Comment: An affine variety over $k$ is an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} A$ together with a morphism $\chi:\operatorname{Spec} A\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ such that $\chi$ is induced by $f:k\to A$ and $A=f(k)[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$ where $x_i\in A$.

Comment: In the context of the definition of an algebraic variety over $k$, when we say "$X_i$ is an affine variety over $k$", we only mean that up to isomorphism.

Comment: Are my two interpretations the same in essence?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your two interpretations.

Comment: We can find an isomorphism $\xi:A\to k[T_0,T_1,\cdots,T_n]/I$ such that $\xi\circ f$ is the canonical morphism $k\to k[T_0,T_1,\cdots,T_n]/I$.